Migrating from Node 16 to Node 20 AWS Elastic Beanstalk from github
I am trying to update our development Elastic Beanstalk instance going from Node 16 to Node 20.  Since I have to change platforms I have to do a Blue/Green deployment.  I create the Elastic Beanstalk environment with the sample application and when I go to the instance Node 20.11.1 and npm 10.2.4 are installed.  Then I try to run a github workflow to create our app but it keeps failing. Here is the yaml script I am using in github:
name: Development/CI Pipeline
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [ 20.11.1 ]

    steps:
      - name: work around permission issue
        run: git config --global --add safe.directory /github/workspace
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - name: Upgrade NPM
        run: npm install -g npm@10.2.4
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run build --if-present
      - run: npm test

      # Don't include node_modules in zip archive
      - run: rm -rf node_modules/

      - name: Generate deployment package
        run: zip -r deploy.zip ./

      - name: Read package.json
        uses: krstphrrr/package-json-version-reader@v1.0.0
        id: package-version

      - run: echo "Version is ${{ steps.package-version.outputs.version }}"
      - run: echo "Run number is ${{ github.run_number }}"

      - name: Deploy to EB
        uses: einaregilsson/beanstalk-deploy@v22
        with:
          aws_access_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws_secret_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET }}
          application_name: MyAppAPI
          environment_name: MyAppDevNode20
          version_label: 'v${{ steps.package-version.outputs.version }}.${{ github.run_number   }}'
          region: us-east-1
          use_existing_version_if_available: true
          deployment_package: deploy.zip
          wait_for_deployment: true

It fails when trying to run some npm commands.  It doesn't seem to install node.  It cleared it but did not re-install.  When I go to the instance node is not installed any more.  I did have to change the script to bring it up to date but not sure what would cause an error. The changes I made were:

node-version: [ 16.19.1 ] to
node-version: [ 20.11.1 ]

uses: actions/checkout@v3 to
uses: actions/checkout@v4

uses: actions/setup-node@v3 to
uses: actions/setup-node@v4

run: npm install -g npm@8.19.3 to
run: npm install -g npm@10.2.4

uses: tyankatsu0105/read-package-version-actions@v1 to
uses: krstphrrr/package-json-version-reader@v1.0.0

uses: einaregilsson/beanstalk-deploy@v10 to
uses: einaregilsson/beanstalk-deploy@v22


Most of these changes were because of the old processes using deprecated node versions.  The one that I was most uncertain about was the one for reading the package version.  I don't know if the replacement package I came up is a correct one but it seemed to be about all I could find and the process did not complain about it.
Any nuggets of knowledge to help me out?
